# Android getting the correct values from an arraylist

Tags: android

Okay I'll try describe this the best way I can.

I have a chat application and I am sending a request to receive a list of public channels.
The string that I receive back from the server is:

```
RESP_PUBLICCHANNELLIST, channelID 1, channelName 1, channelID 2, channelName 2
```

And when I add this list to my AlertDialog, it shows each channel and channel ID as a separate channel. I would like to just have the channel name in the AlertDialog and have the channel ID in a map with a key value to it. Is this possible?

Here is my current code I am having problems with:

```
 public void ShowPublicChannelList(){

     String PublicChannelsPost = "";
     PublicChannelsPost = ExecuteCommand(_chatProtocol.ShowPublicChannelList());
     System.out.println("Public Channels: " + PublicChannelsPost);
     _publicChannels.add("New..");

     List <String> responseList = Arrays.asList(PublicChannelsPost.split(","));
        if (responseList.contains("RESP_PUBLICCHANNELLIST")){
            for (int i = 1; i < responseList.size(); i++) {
                _publicChannels.add(responseList.get(i));
                System.out.println("Channels: " + _publicChannels);
            }   
                SetPublicChannelList(_publicChannels);
                }
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're unsure about how to parse the server response into a mapping of a channel ID and name? You could simply step through your list of separated strings with steps of two and populate every pair into a single map entry. This does make the assumption that a channel id is always followed by a channel name (or  vice versa: every name is preceded by an id).

```
if (responseList.contains("RESP_PUBLICCHANNELLIST")) {
    Map<String, String> channelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i=1; i<responseList.size(); i+=2) {
        if (i+1 >= responseList.size()) break; // this only happens if not every id has name
        channelMap.put(responseList.get(i), responseList.get(i+1));
    }

    // print values to check correct mapping
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> channel : channelMap.entrySet()) System.out.println(channel.getKey() + " | " +channel.getValue());
}
```

As you can see, I simply break the loop if the length of the source list is 'unexpected'. you might want to consider implementing something more robust, unless you're absolutely sure the illegal case will never arise.